# Configurar oci8 no xampp php7.18

Tags: php, xampp

Estou tentando configurar o oci no xampp com php7.1.8.

Ativei a linha `extension=php_oci8_12c.dll` no `php.ini`, mas ao iniciar o serviço ele dá seguinte mensagem.

> Não foi possível localizar o ponto de entrada do procedimento `OCIContextGetValue` na biblioteca de vínculo dinâmico OCI.dll

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá adventistaam, a resposta lhe ajudou, sobrou alguma duvida em relação a ela?

Comment: Eu voltei pra versão anterior mesmo a que não dava problemas

Comment: @adventistaam conseguiu resolver, estou com um problema parecido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você baixou o cliente incompatível/errado para usar com esta dll do PHP, possivelmente a arquitetura do teu PHP e do cliente Oracle são diferentes, por exemplo o php é 64bit e o cliente é 32bit.

Outras possibilidades:

- você baixou um cliente de versão errada
- você não instalou o cliente
- você baixou um OCI.dll e colocou na mesma pasta do PHP (remova-o se tiver feito isso "desfaça")

Independente do que fez anteriormente, desfaça (fazendo os backups necessários antes) e então primeiro vamos identificar a arquitetura e alguns dados relevantes acaso você queira instalar uma extensão externa, crie um arquivo chamado info.php e adicione isto:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Veja as informações relevantes antes de instalar o cliente do Oracle (no caso pra ti só a arquitetura é relevante):

[image: phpinfo]

Depois de verificar a arquitetura e o compilador baixe o cliente apropriado, provavelmente o teu PHP é 64bit, mas não estou certo:

- Cliente oracle 64ibt: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html
- Cliente oracle 32ibt: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html

Outros clientes:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html

Remova o cliente que já tem instalado e instale o que baixou.